# How to bookmark debugger links for PhpStorm?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, phpstorm, xdebug

When I am trying to generate bookmarklets on the following page: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/

The following picture appears

[image]

suggesting to bookmark links below. Unfortunately, Chrome does not allow to bookmarks any link.

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Few ways:

**1.** Fast: just drag and drop it on bookmark bar in Chrome

**2.** A bit longer -- use "Copy link address" option from that menu and then manually create bookmark:

- Use "Paste" from right click menu on bookmark toolbar
- or the same ("Paste") but on any existing bookmark (new one will be created after current one)

This way you will have to edit the title manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll appreciate the Xdebug helper extension for Chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc

Much more comfortable than bookmarks...